# Why does git push give me "Anonymous access to repo#### denied" error?

Tags: git, push, credentials

I've got a windows 7 setup behind a corporate proxy and cntlm to avoid auth problems. Unfortunately, every time I do push a repo:

```
$ git push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/master:master
```

I've got the following errors:

```
remote: Anonymous access to oats4goats/EloquentJS.git denied.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/oats4goats/EloquentJS.git/'"
```

although it prompts me the credentials and I explicitly specify my username and pass:

```
Username for 'https://github.com': oats4goats
Password for 'https://oats4goats@github.com': ************
```

Moreover when I try to use credential-helper:

```
git config credential.helper store
```

it purges the .git-credentials file content instead of adding my credentials there. For me it looks like it doesn't take a user's input of the username/pass, but I don't know why...

At the same time git clone works just fine.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: For the credential helper part, could you ensure your remote url has your username in it? git remote set-url origin https://oats4goats@github.com/oats4goats/EloquentJS`. That way, the helper knows what user's password it is looking for.

Comment: Try to use ssh instead of https.

Comment: @Pierre-JeanBergeron, I can't use SSH unfortunately... I have only http ports opened.

Comment: @VonC, like this it knows the username in advance but it still asks for the pass and gives the same 'anonymous access' error at the end. And .get-credentials is still empty. By the way, I was wondering if anybody can explain what's _netrc file and how it corresponds to .git-credentials file? Thanks.

Comment: @DimitryKozlov _netrc is used by curl, and not related to .git-credentials. See for instance http://stackoverflow.com/a/18362082/6309

Comment: I even extended the original url to include the pass, but it doesn't work as well. Really weird...

Comment: GitHub offers SSH over the HTTPS ports: https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/